# python selenium dropdown error

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I did lots of things to solve this problem... but any answer can't solve my problem.

I want to select drop down option.

This is my homepage's html code

```
<div class="selectric-wrapper">
<div class="selectric-hide-select">
<select id="ymd_birth1" data-reactid=".2mlafrhlvk.2.0.2.1.1.1.0.0" tabindex="0"><option data-reactid=".2mlafrhlvk.2.0.2.1.1.1.0.0.$0">2015</option>
<option data-reactid=".2mlafrhlvk.2.0.2.1.1.1.0.0.$1">2014</option>
<option data-reactid=".2mlafrhlvk.2.0.2.1.1.1.0.0.$2">2013</option>
<option data-reactid=".2mlafrhlvk.2.0.2.1.1.1.0.0.$3">2012</option>
<option data-reactid=".2mlafrhlvk.2.0.2.1.1.1.0.0.$4">2011</option>
```

and this is my python code.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ymd_birth1']/option[text()='1994']").click()
```

When I printed all options by

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ymd_birth1"))
print select.options
print [o.text for o in select.options]
```

The result was terrible...

like..

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="cdadecb9-0706-4383-a6bf-e1a2211e56ba", element="{7a3e2067-6a3c-4e21-816b-93d8c38288be}")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="cdadecb9-0706-4383-a6bf-e1a2211e56ba", element="{53bf8d75-a380-4a45-a1e8-7315505589bf}")>]

[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'....]
```

please help me!! I can't solve this problem for 5 hours....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't click on drop down option when the combo box is closed. Use `Select` class with explicit wait instead

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
dropDown = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ymd_birth1')))
select = Select(dropDown)
select.select_by_visible_text('1994')
```

Comment: It doesn't work, too. with ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: Another error is coming..

dropDown = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(By.ID, 'ymd_birth1'))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: @ChangHakYeon Add another set of brackets around `By.ID, 'ymd_birth1'` :  dropDown = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ymd_birth1')))